# ¿Como adjuntar archivos en android para enviar por email?

Tags: java, android

Buenas noches, resulta que tengo mi aplicación en la cual genero un pdf, para luego querer enviar un email y adjuntar el archivo pdf, el archivo pdf me lo genera bien, pero no se como hacer para adjuntar el archivo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si realizas lo que te indican y te funciona, lo que puedes hacer es listar en cajas de texto los nombres de los archivos que tienes luego deberías de crear un metodo para que cuando selecciones el archivo que tu quieres se le envíe el correo. Solo deberías de poder listar todos los archivos que tienes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes que obtener el URI del archivo, tal que así:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CALC/REPORTS/",pdfname ));
```

**Un ejemplo:**

```
String[] mailto = {""};
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CALC/REPORTS/",pdfname ));
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Calc PDF Report");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");
emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using:"));
```

**Actualización: Abrir carpeta:**

```
private void showFile(Uri fileUri){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "file/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

También:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/"))); /** Reemplazar con tu propio uri */
```

**Adjuntar varios PDFS:**

```
final Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
ei.setType("plain/text");
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"me@somewhere.nodomain"});
ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "That one works");
```

Y luego tienes que añadir los URIS:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ei, "Sending multiple attachment"), 12345);
```

Comment: Gracias Patrick, pero estoy un poco perdido, no se bien donde va ese codigo que me mandaste, osea logico que ira en mi activity, pero para referenciarle el boton y me abra la galeria de archivos, como se podria hacer?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias @Patrick, tengo una duda, con tu codigo podre enviar mas de 1 pdf? me refiero a que genera pdf's distintos, y me da error en esta linea de codigo:
`Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CALC/REPORTS/",pdfname ));` pdfname deberia ir con comillas? ""

Comment: Actualizado la respuesta adjuntando varios Pdfs. Un saludo

Comment: Si, pdfname es el nombre entre comillas

Comment: Los pdf que genera mi aplicacion cambian de nombre, como se puede lograr que siempre se envien distintos pdf? aun no logro completar el codigo, estoy viendo aca (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686209/attaching-a-pdf-to-an-email-from-android-app-file-size-is-zero) y creo que podria ayudarme tambien.

Comment: `emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ViewAllAccountFragment".selectac+" PDF Report");`lo que tengo en comillas no esta resuelto, como se puede arreglar?. Saludos.

Comment: Es simplemente un texto. Actualizo la respuesta: emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hi PDF is attached in this mail. ");

Answer (score 5):

No solo puede adjuntar un .pdf, puedes adjuntar cualquier tipo de archivos, en este caso el tipo que sería determinado por el **[MIME TYPE](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)** que para un archivo .pdf debe ser `"application/pdf"`.

El adjuntar un archivo al enviar lo puedes realizar mediante un Intent donde defines la [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) el recurso si es únicamente uno o un listado de [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)´s para enviar varios archivos:

```
        String archivoPDF = "archivo.pdf";
        //Obtiene la Uri del recurso.
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFS/", archivoPDF));
        //Crea intent para enviar el email.
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("application/pdf");
        //Agrega email o emails de destinatario.
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@dominio.com" });
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivo PDF.");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hola te envío un archivo PDF."); 
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviar e-mail mediante:"));
```

Tu pregunta refiere :

> **¿Como adjuntar archivos en android studio para enviar por email?**

Si lo que deseas es adjuntar varios archivos, debes crear un Listado de  [Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)'s que contendrán las rutas de los archivos.

```
  //Crear una Lista de Uris.
  List<Uri> listUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
  //Agrega elementos (como ejemplo 3 elementos).
  lstUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFS/", "archivo1.pdf")););
  lstUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFS/", "archivo2.pdf")););
  lstUris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFS/", "archivo3.pdf")););

    //Crea intent para enviar el email.
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("application/pdf");            
    //Agrega email o emails de destinatario.
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "email@dominio.com" });
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF.");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hola te envío archivos PDF."); 
    //Define listado de Uris de cada archivo.
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  listUris);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviar e-mail mediante:"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, pero quiero seleccionar yo el archivo para enviar mediante un boton de adjuntar, lo tengo hecho pero se me crashea la aplicacion

Comment: El error es relacionado a como concatenas Strings:emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ViewAllAccountFragment".selectac+" PDF Report");   el segundo párametro de putExtra() es incorrecto, como sugerencia cambia a: Strings:emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "anexo archivo PDF.");