# 'No se puede adjuntar archivo' Email Intent

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

Estoy creando una aplicación en Android Studio donde genero un pdf y posteriormente lo mando por correo pero al momento de mandar a llamar el intent la aplicacion de correo me genera los correos a los que los voy a añadir y tambien el titulo pero no puedo adjuntar el archivo aparece un mensaje que dice 'No se puede adjuntar el archivo'

```
    Uri uri= Uri.parse("content:/" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            + "/" + nom_dir + "/"+ nom_doc);
    Intent emailintent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, bien);
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Report "+ fecha());
    emailintent.setType("aplplication/PDF");
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent,"Send E-mail using:"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 3 razones por las cuales no puedas adjuntar el archivo

- El archivo no existe.
- La ruta al archivo es incorrecta.
- No tienes definido y aceptado el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  [Error al mostrar el directorio externo de archivos en android 6.0 (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external)

Debes asegurar los punto mencionados, pero al ver tu codigo, la definicion del archivo para obtener la Uri es incorrecta, te sugiero primeramente ademas validar si en realidad existe el archivo en la ruta especificada:

```
String ruta = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
File file = new File(ruta);
if(file.exists()){ //Archivo existe!

 Uri uri= Uri.parse(ruta);
    Intent emailintent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, bien);
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Report "+ fecha());
    emailintent.setType("aplplication/PDF");
    emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent,"Send E-mail using:"));

}else{ //Archivo NO existe!

  Log.e("Envio", "Archivo no existe en ruta: " + ruta);

}
```

Te sugiero revisar esta pregunta ,  ahi viene un ejemplo de como realizarlo:

[¿Como adjuntar archivos en android para enviar por email?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30123/como-adjuntar-archivos-en-android-para-enviar-por-email)